# Hadoop 2: Setting up Hadoop 2 code in eclipse to modify source code and run/test?

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I want to get the latest version of Hadoop (YARN/Hadoop 2) and play around with it by changing some of the code under the hood.

I was wondering if anyone can provide a step by step guide on setting up such a Hadoop development environment on eclipse, where I can make changes to the code, compile it and then install/test it out on my local machine?

I am a newbie in terms of Hadoop and I did manage to find some guides online but they seem to be very different from each other and I didn't know which one I should follow and why etc, so any tips or resources would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you find this useful i had it bookmarked http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/EclipseEnvironment